# Android parsing a JSON message

Tags: android, json

I'm trying to parse the following JSON string

```
String _message = "GetXTRONResult: \"[{\"xtron\":\"Acub1\"},{\"xtron\":\"Acub2\"},{\"xtron\":\"Acub3A\"}]\"";

JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(_message);

//Try to convert to array
JSONArray array = jsonObj.getJSONArray("GetXTRONResult");  //FAILS !
```

What is the best way to parse the above please?

**UPDATE:**
This is what the value is during debugging:

```
{"GetXTRONResult":"[{\"xtron\":\"Acub1\"},{\"xtron\":\"Acub2\"},{\"xtron\":\"Acub3A\"}]"}

org.json.JSONException: Value .... at GetXTRONResultof type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray
```

**SOLUTION THAT WORKED FOR ME:**
I had to use the iterator as follows:

```
ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(_message);
Iterator<?> keys = jsonObj.keys();
if (keys.hasNext()) {
   JSONArray array = new JSONArray((String) jsonObj.get((String) keys.next()));
for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); ++i) {  
    list.add(array.getJSONObject(i).getString("xtron").toString()); 
}
```

Comment: I found a usefull subject [here][1].

Hope it will help you ;)


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9605913/how-to-parse-json-in-android

Comment: Your json is not valid

Comment: It won't even compile because you haven't escaped quotes `"` inside other quotes.

Comment: your json isn't valid. first test your json here http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: i copied it directly from browser and i forgot to add the quotes. I revised the question and now its valid. Any idea appreciated

Comment: test your json here : http://jsonlint.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have some errors in your json string, like `"[`.

You can't use quotes that wrap your list.

This one should work:

```
String _message = "{\"GetXTRONResult\": [{\"xtron\":\"Acub1\"},{\"xtron\":\"Acub2\"},{\"xtron\":\"Acub3A\"}]}";

    JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(_message);

    //Try to convert to array
    JSONArray array = jsonObj.getJSONArray("GetXTRONResult");  

    System.out.println(array);
```

Output: `[{"xtron":"Acub1"},{"xtron":"Acub2"},{"xtron":"Acub3A"}]`

Answer (score 0):

To avoid your confusion when making JSON in  java/android

you could use single quote (') instead of double quote (") for JSON inside Java Code

For example:

from

```
"{\"xtron\":\"Acub1\"},{\"xtron\":\"Acub2\"},{\"xtron\":\"Acub3A\"}"
```

to be something like this

```
"{'xtron':'Acub1'},{'xtron':'Acub2'},{'xtron':'Acub3A'}"
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're looking for:

```
JSONObject rootObj = new JSONObject(jsonString);
String theArrayJSON = rootObj.getJSONArray("GetXTRONResult");

JSONObject theArray = new JSONObject(theArrayJSON);
```